# JAVA program run problem

Tags: programming

I have install java in my computer. when i doing compile java program it is successfully done but when i try to run program it show error like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Example2 : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: Example2. Program will exit.
```

what should i do??

Comment: we need information like what is your program and how are you trying to run it.

Comment: With only that information is hard to point out the exact problem. How have you installed Java (`apt-get`/Software Center/Oracle installer)? Which Java version you have (`java -version`)? Ubuntu version and arch? Check you are not compiling your app with a newer version of the JRE you are using to run the program (ex: compiling with OpenJDK7 and running with Oracle JDK6).

Comment: java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.5) (6b27-1.12.5-0ubuntu0.11.10.1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not mistaking this error is thrown if your virtual machine tries to run a program with different minor and major versions. Your number is 51.0 which means that your program is supported by J2SE and you try to run it with a newer version.
To fix your problem you should make sure that you got the newest version of the Java JRE

Comment: i have install both JDK&JRE 6 and 7 version.      class Example2
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
  int num; 
  num = 100; 
  System.out.println("This is num: " + num);
  num = num * 2;
  System.out.print("The value of num * 2 is ");
  System.out.println(num);
 }
}  this is my simple program

Comment: so your problem is that you compiled your program with v6 and try to run it with v7. But I'm not quite sure how to change the wrong path on ubuntu... :(   edit: your program is fine there is no mistake with it.

Comment: than what should i do??